# An n-segment sequence

Tags: cipher, number-sequence, letter-sequence

```
      _                 _         
_  a |_  b |   c |   d     e   | f   | g |_  h     i     j/*End of Sequence*/
   a |_  b   | c |   d |_  e |   f     g |_  h     i |   j/*End of Sequence*/
```

You find a piece of paper in the print tray with the above characters printed. You notice that the space between the *h* and the *i* is blank. What should be placed there and why?

Hint

> Read the title again.

---

P.S. I've used both [number-sequence](/questions/tagged/number-sequence) and [letter-sequence](/questions/tagged/letter-sequence) because I don't want to reveal what kind of a sequence it is. Will [enigmatic-puzzles](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzles) be valid here as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing should be placed there.

> It is the sequence of segments that aren't lit up when a 7-segment display goes from zero to nine.  The ninth term in the sequence is nothing because all 7 segments are lit up for the digit eight.

Comment: That looks like the right answer, but if so, then h is wrong and should have the middle segment shown.

Comment: @GordonK Sorry. I'll edit it.